# Firebase values are properly pulled but cannot be accessed?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, firebase, react-native

I'm running into a weird issue where once I push a value to a Firebase object, two things happen:

1. I can't access it in the array I receive when I pull the object from Firebase.
2. The array I receive has no `length` property.

Here is what my Firebase structure looks like:

```
"user_solutions": {
    "0":
        {
            "user_id": 0,
            "clue_id": 0,
            "hunt_id": 0,
            "completed": 1
        },
    "1":
        {
            "user_id": 0,
            "clue_id": 1,
            "hunt_id": 0,
            "completed": 0
        },
    "2":
        {
            "user_id": 0,
            "clue_id": 1,
            "hunt_id": 1,
            "completed": 0
        }
  },
  "-KHxBMZwVMzyiMIcbMdr":
      {
         clue_id: 1,
         completed: 0,
         hunt_id: 0,
         user_id: 0
     }
```

Here is the problematic function:

```
userSolutionsRef.orderByChild('user_id').startAt(0).endAt(0).once('value', (snap) => {
        var solution = snap.val(); 
        for (var i = 0; i < solution.length; i++) {
            if (solution[i].hunt_id == 0) {
                solutionsForThisHunt.push(solution[i]);
            }
        }
        this.populateArray(solutionsForThisHunt);
    });
```

When I run the debugger, `solution` has the value `Object {0: Object, 1: Object, 2: Object, -KHxBMZwVMzyiMIcbMdr: Object}`,  but the `length` property is undefined. `solutionsForThisHunt` never gets populated. Also, I can access the objects individually in the debugger via `snap.val()[0]`/`snap.val()[1]`/`snap.val()[2]`, but for some reason when I try accessing `snap.val()[3]` it is undefined, although it should be populated.

Comment: Does `snap.val` return a real array or another iterable? What does `Array.isArray` return? (https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray)

Comment: You are right! I was under the impression it returned an array but it was just an iterable. Your solution worked, thanks.

Comment: Firebase will not return an array here, because it looks like you stored your keys as strings. [Storing them as integers would make a difference](https://www.firebase.com/docs/rest/guide/understanding-data.html#section-arrays-in-firebase), although I'd always recommend to not [depend on array semantics when it comes to Firebase](https://www.firebase.com/docs/rest/guide/saving-data.html#section-post).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

solution seems to be an object with keys, rather than an array. You could do the following

```
var solution = snap.val(); 
var array = Object.keys(solution).map(key => ({ ...solution[key], id: key }));
for ....
```